# Migrate Maven Packages from Azure DevOps Artifacts

Tags: maven, azure-devops

I am looking to migrate Maven packages from Azure Artifacts to another Azure DevOps Organisation, still using Azure Artifacts.

I thought this would be an easy task however it is appearing very difficult, the package contains two jar files.

Is there any way I can download the Maven package, and push it directly to another Artifact Library?

Comment: If the two organizations are in the same AAD, you can add the feed in another organization as an upstream source.  See [Add a feed in a different organization as an upstream source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/how-to/set-up-upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#add-a-feed-in-a-different-organization-as-an-upstream-source).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a local copy of the artifacts, change the destination url in your configuration and deploy the artifact.

```
mvn clean install
```

Change the repository and distribution management URL to point your azure devOps destination ( you can do that by changing the **setting.xml** search for the **altSnapshotDeploymentRepository** & **altReleaseDeploymentRepository** fields and change the urls)

```
mvn deploy
```

Comment: problem with that is there is multiple versions spanning back years which are still in use, so yes that would work for the current version, but I need to deploy older versions where there is no way to track the commit id or build id and unfortunately, they did not using tagging!

Comment: Ah I see, then you should publich manually the artifacts. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563290/how-to-manually-publish-a-file-to-azure-artifacts It may be helpful